# Docker dotnet watch run error: Unable to bind to https://localhost:5000 on the IPv6 loopback interface

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

As the title indicates, i have a container that is unable to bind from host port to container port. I tried searching for similar issues, but have not found any related to using dotnet watch in a docker container since Microsoft introduced the `microsoft/dotnet` docker repo with dotnet watch built into the sdk image.

Any suggestions as to what i am doing wrong are much appreciated.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.301-sdk as build
ENV DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER 1
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore
EXPOSE 5000-5001
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "watch", "run", "--no-restore"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:

  esportapp:
    container_name: esportapp
    image: esportapp:dev
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Docker/dev.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - esportapp.volume:/app
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "5001:5001"

volumes:
  esportapp.volume:
```

**Complete error:**

```
esportapp    | Hosting environment: Development
esportapp    | Content root path: /app
esportapp    | Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
esportapp    | Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
esportapp    | Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
esportapp    | warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
esportapp    |       Unable to bind to https://localhost:5001 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Cannot assign requested address'.
esportapp    | warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
esportapp    |       Unable to bind to http://localhost:5000 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Cannot assign requested address'.
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Just ran into this problem myself.  I don't think `dotnet watch run` plays nicely with localhost type urls.  Try setting your hosting url to `https://0.0.0.0:5000` in your container.

In the dockerfile with:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "watch", "run", "--no-restore", "--urls", "https://0.0.0.0:5000"]
```

Or in launchSettings.json like:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "[Put your project name here]": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER": "true"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://0.0.0.0:5000/"
    }
  }
}
```

Now to get it to automatically reload from within the container you have to use the polling file watcher.  That's what the second environment variable is for.  (This is pretty common, you've got to do this with webpack, angular, etc).

In your case, you need to change the `esportsapp.volume` to a directory on your host:

```
volumes:
  - ./:/app
```

That will map the /app volume in your container to the docker-compose directory.  The problem you're facing is that the app is built in a volume on your project's default docker-compose network, so when you change a file in the source directory, it's not actually changing in that volume.  With this fix, however, you'll run into the problem of the dotnet restore and dotnet watch inside the container changing your host's files.  There's a fix for all of that, if you're interested...

**My Usual .Net Core App Docker setup**

To debug, run: `docker-compose -f run.yml up --build`

To build a release: `docker-compose -f build.yml up --build`

**Project structure**

```
/                                               # source control root
/build.yml                                      # docker-compose file for building a release
/run.yml                                        # docker-compose file for running locally & debugging
/project                                        # an application
/project/build.Dockerfile                       # the docker container that will build "project" for release
/project/run.Dockerfile                         # the docker container that will build and run "project" locally for debugging
/project/.dockerignore                          # speeds up container builds by excluding large directories like "packages" or "node_modules"
/project/src                                    # where I hide my source codez
/project/src/Project.sln
/project/src/Project/Project.csproj
/project/src/Project/Directory.Build.props      # keeps a docker mapped volume from overwriting .dlls on your host
/project/src/Project.Data/Project.Data.csproj   # typical .Net project structure
/web-api                                        # another application...
```

**Directory.Build.props** (put this in the same folder as your .csproj, keeps your `dotnet watch run` command from messing with the source directory on your host)

```
<Project>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/obj/**/*</DefaultItemExcludes>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/bin/**/*</DefaultItemExcludes>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER)' == 'true'">
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/obj/container/</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
    <BaseOutputPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/bin/container/</BaseOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER)' != 'true'">
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/obj/local/</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
    <BaseOutputPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/bin/local/</BaseOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

**run.yml** (docker-compose.yml for debugging)

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  project:
    build:
      context: ./project
      dockerfile: run.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5000:80
    volumes:
      - ./project/src/Project:/app
```

**run.Dockerfile** (the Dockerfile for debugging)

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk

# install the .net core debugger
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install unzip
RUN apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install procps
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN curl -sSL https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh | bash /dev/stdin -v latest -l /vsdbg

VOLUME /app
WORKDIR /app

CMD dotnet watch run --urls http://0.0.0.0:80
```

**build.yml** (the docker-compose.yml for building release versions)

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  project:
    build:
      context: ./project
      dockerfile: build.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./project:/app
```

**build.Dockerfile** (the Dockerfile for building release versions)

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk

VOLUME /app

# restore as a separate layer to speed up builds
WORKDIR /src
COPY src/Project/Project.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore

COPY src/Project/ .
CMD dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/out/
```

Comment: I followed your answer to connect the url, but I can't get the auto-reloading on file changes to work.  My guess is that I am doing something wrong in the docker-compose.yml file with the volumes. Any suggestions?

Comment: @BryceHayden Updated the answer with a fix for ya

Comment: Yeah I have that variable set up already...I will play around with it some and if I can't find the answer then I'll hit you up

Comment: @BryceHayden I misread your question on the volumes initially, I've added something that should help

Comment: It took me a little while to figure out, as my folder structure is different than yours but I finally got it running. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @RyanVice sure is - but that's a different topic entirely, check out this article: https://www.humankode.com/ssl/create-a-selfsigned-certificate-for-nginx-in-5-minutes

Answer (score 4):

There's a simple solution, add the following two lines into your docker-compose.yml file, and the error will disappear.

```
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+;http://+;
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining what the + means? I tried this answer in my docker-compose and still get same error.

Comment: @OlusegunOdumosu according to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-5.0#endpoint-configuration , "Host names, *, and +, aren't special. Anything not recognized as a valid IP address or localhost binds to all IPv4 and IPv6 IPs."

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to share one other issue I ran recently while containerizing a set of projects even if everything is configured correctly. Hope might help someone else.

Very inconspicuous but some of projects had in `Program.cs`:

```
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
{
    config.Sources.Clear();
    ...
```

Which removes all of the sources and `ChainedConfigurationSource` specifically that leads to the error above.

Comment: I had a verision of this - some code had been checked in that added its own IConfiguration singleton - which essentially cleared the config sources

Comment: @Andrey: I ran to the same issue today, is there a way to rebind the configurations? or explicitly specifying somewhere in the config? that would help!

Answer (score 3):

I solved the same issue in the following way:

1. Added the following in `appsettings.json` to force Kestrel to listen to port  80.

```
"Kestrel": {
  "EndPoints": {
    "Http": {
      "Url": "http://+:80"
    }
  }
}
```

2. Exposed the port in `dockerfile`

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80

EXPOSE 80
```

3. Ran the container using the below command.

```
docker run -p 8080:80 <image-name>:<tag>
```

4. The app exposed on `http://localhost:8080/`