# Creating a simple dot net core and mysql docker container composition

Tags: mysql, docker, .net-core

I'm new to docker and I'm trying to create a simple dot net core web api and mysql container composition.

I've done the following:

1. Generated a starter project with the dot net sdk:
   `dotnet new webapi -o example-app`
2. Created a Dockerfile in the project with the following content:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "watch", "run"]
```

3. Created a docker-compose.yml file with the following content:

```
version: "3"

services:
  dot-net-rest-api:
    container_name: docker-dot-net-rest-api
    restart: always
    build: .
    environment:
      - DBHOST=dot-net-mysql-db
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports: 
      - '5000:80'
    depends_on:
      - dot-net-mysql-db

  dot-net-mysql-db:
    container_name: docker-dot-net-mysql-db
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dot_net_rest_api_db
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: user
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - mysqldbdata:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  mysqldbdata:
```

When i run `docker-compose up` I get the following output:

```
Creating network "example-app_default" with the default driver
Creating docker-dot-net-mysql-db ... done
Creating docker-dot-net-rest-api ... done
Attaching to docker-dot-net-mysql-db, docker-dot-net-rest-api
docker-dot-net-rest-api | /bin/sh: 1: [dotnet: not found
docker-dot-net-mysql-db | 2019-08-18T13:36:03.515008Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
docker-dot-net-mysql-db | 2019-08-18T13:36:03.515151Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.17) starting as process 1
docker-dot-net-mysql-db | 2019-08-18T13:36:04.256200Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting crash recovery...
docker-dot-net-mysql-db | 2019-08-18T13:36:04.267569Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] Crash recovery finished.
docker-dot-net-mysql-db | 2019-08-18T13:36:04.311086Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
docker-dot-net-mysql-db | 2019-08-18T13:36:04.315279Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
docker-dot-net-mysql-db | 2019-08-18T13:36:04.357081Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.17'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
docker-dot-net-mysql-db | 2019-08-18T13:36:04.481530Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
docker-dot-net-rest-api exited with code 127
docker-dot-net-rest-api exited with code 127
docker-dot-net-rest-api exited with code 127
docker-dot-net-rest-api exited with code 127
docker-dot-net-rest-api exited with code 127
docker-dot-net-rest-api exited with code 127
docker-dot-net-rest-api exited with code 127
...
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest you follow the setup at `https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnetcore-build`. Under `Example usage` there is a working example.

Comment: Maybe use `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapp.dll"]`?

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your configuration.

Main: you base your Dockerfile on deprecated image - [microsoft/aspnetcore-build](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnetcore-build)
I changed it to `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2` which contains *dotnet watch* tool inside.

Moreover to use *Dotnet watch* inside Docker you should declare environment variable:

```
ENV DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER 1
```

otherwise file-change events may not trigger (I can't find impartial source of this information but I've seen it in several articles and one book).

Furthermore there is problem with *127.0.0.1* address in *dotnet watch* inside container, so I have changed:
`"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"`
in *launchSettings.json* to:
`"applicationUrl": "http://0.0.0.0:5000"`.
Explanation is written here: [Docker dotnet watch run error: Unable to bind to https://localhost:5000 on the IPv6 loopback interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51188774/docker-dotnet-watch-run-error-unable-to-bind-to-https-localhost5000-on-the-i)

Third mistake is *docker-compose* port bindings which you defined for app - *'5000:80'* -
it should be: *'80:5000'* because left side is port for host, right side is port inside container.

Also you don't need to *EXPOSE* port from you app container, DB won't access it - app will access DB.

Now with simple `docker-compose up --build` you can run the system and see results from browser: `http://localhost:80/api/values`.

My suggestion is to delve a little into what is going on in *Dockerfile* and *docker-compose* file, to understand the flow and
to be able to debug it.

I have written [introduction to docker](https://www.softwaredeveloper.blog/multi-project-dotnet-core-solution-in-docker-image) which explains example *Dockerfile* line by line and
[introduction to docker compose](https://www.softwaredeveloper.blog/docker-compose-introduction-dotnet-core-app-composed-with-mysql-database), based on .NET Core app composed with MySQL DB.
Whole [source code from the latter article](https://github.com/SoftwareDeveloperBlog/Docker-compose-dotnet-core-and-mysql) is hosted on GitHub - if you want to skip article you can just see working example.

I hope you find these references helpful :)