# Docker "Unable to bind to"

Tags: docker, .net-core

I have built my first .net core 3.0 docker image but when attempting to run the image, docker returns some errors.

I have tried many configurations of ports. I have tried navigating to localhost ip rather than localhost. I have also googled and googled some more.

```
PS C:\Users\jamie\source\repos\Angular\Angular> docker run -it -p 8080:80 angular
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
      Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      No XML encryptor configured. Key {b5292a1f-2d9a-456a-815f-90f19bfe21b1} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to bind to http://localhost:5000 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Cannot assign requested address'.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to bind to https://localhost:5001 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Cannot assign requested address'.
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /app
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

Also, here is my dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/publish .
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "Angular.dll"]
```

Comment: A message like “Now listening on: ...localhost...” means the process will be unreachable from outside the container; you need to make that say “0.0.0.0” (or IPv6 “::”).  I don’t know how to tell .net that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are just warning, but I think the issue from the application port, as the server is running on different as you see

```
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
```

so try to bind `5000` or `5001`

```
docker run -it -p 8080:5000 angular

or

docker run -it -p 8080:5001 angular
```

As mention by David you also need to make listen 
Try to add 
`ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "Angular.dll", "--urls", "http://0.0.0.0:5000"]` if not then follow the answer from the link in comment

Comment: Thanks but neither work. Chrome returns ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE and all errors in docker console come up still.

Comment: Were you able to run this on host `dotnet Angular.dll`? And then access browser

Comment: as mentioned by David, you check this answer too. you might need to change the some configuation in your app config. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51188774/docker-dotnet-watch-run-error-unable-to-bind-to-https-localhost5000-on-the-i